# What application is responsible for saving num lock preferences of a user?

Tags: numlock

On a normal installation, if I unlock the numpad, it will remain so every time I log in. However, on my minimal installs, numpad is always locked at every log in. What do I need to install to let the computer remember my num lock preferences?

I did not find the [NumLock](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock) article of Community Ubuntu Documentation helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing `numlockx` solved the problem. Numpad was unlocked when I rebooted and logged in.

```
sudo apt-get install numlockx
```